# Sed : Add a line at the starting of each TCL proc

Tags: sed, tcl

I have a TCL proc like this, & want to add a line after the start of the proc, the puts "puts " entered myproc" " line

```
proc myproc { {filename "input.txt"}
{var1 "x"} 
{var2 "y"}
{var3 "z"}
{var4 ""}
{var5 "0"}
{var6 "0"}
{var7 0}
} {
puts " entered myproc"
```

Can you help?
& it should also work for 
    proc myproc2 { N val } { 
    puts " entered myproc"
    # comment line 
    set ret {} for { set i 0 } { $i < $N } { incr i } { lappend ret $val } 
    return $ret 
    }

Comment: Each Var1/2/3..is on a seprate line because of the size & some legacy code

Comment: Format your question and give sample input and output.

Comment: Sample in file is below, sample out file is above, i need to add just a string like the puts : proc myproc { {filename "input.txt"}
{var1 "x"} 
{var2 "y"}
{var3 "z"}
{var4 ""}
{var5 "0"}
{var6 "0"}
{var7 0}
} {

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: want to execute a proc , before the start of every proc , so that i can get the callstack/or proc name , depends on what debug im doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want to do is get an execution trace of your code, such as a call stack dump etc, then you don't need to modify your source code at all. You can use tcl itself to do it for you.

Tcl has no reserved keywords, none at all. Not even `proc` is reserved. You can therefore redefine it:

```
rename proc _proc

# Now proc no longer exists but we have _proc instead.
# Use it to redefine "proc":

_proc proc {name arguments body} {
    set body "puts \"entered $name\";$body"
    _proc $name $arguments $body
}
```

Just do that before running any of your own code and you'll find that every proc prints out when it's being entered on each call.

This is how a lot of tcl debuggers and profilers work - using tcl to redifine itself.

---

From your comments it looks like you're trying to also print how deep the stack is with each call. To do that you need to add more code to each proc definition. The most straightforward way is of course something like this:

```
_proc proc {name arguments body} {
    set preamble"set dist2top \[info level\];puts \"\$dist2top entered $name\""
    set body "$preamble;$body"
    _proc $name $arguments $body
}
```

But as you can see, writing code inside strings can quickly become unmanagable. There are several tricks you can use to make it more manageable. One of the more common is to split `$body` by line and use list commands to manipulate code. It should reduce at least one level of quoting hell. My favorite is to use a templating technique similar to how you'd write html templates in MVC frameworks. I usually use `string map` for this:

```
_proc proc {name arguments body} {
    _proc $name $arguments [string map [list %NAME% $name %BODY% $body] {
        set dist2top [info level]
        puts "$dist2top entered: %NAME%"
        %BODY%
    }]
}
```

The last argument in the `_proc` definition is just a string but it looks like a code block which makes it easier to read. No nasty quoting hell with this technique.

Comment: but im unable to get the whole stack: rename proc _proc

# Now proc no longer exists but we have _proc instead.
# Use it to redefine "proc":

_proc proc {name arguments body} {
   set distanceToTop [info level]
    set body "puts \"$distanceToTop : entered $name\";$body"
    _proc $name $arguments $body
}
proc A { } {
    B 3
}
proc B { x } {
    C [incr x] 2
}
proc C { x y {z 5} } {
    D [incr x] [incr y] $z
}
proc D { x y z} {
    E [incr x] [incr y] [incr z]
}

Comment: proc E {x y z } {
        puts " in proc E"
        set distanceToTop [info level]
        puts "distance to top inside proc E is : $distanceToTop"
}
output : > A
1 : entered A
1 : entered B
1 : entered C
1 : entered D
1 : entered E
 in proc E
distance to top inside proc E is : 5

Comment: You're calling `info level` too early. You need to call it in the $body, not when you're defining the proc.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk '/^ *proc/ {$0 = $0 "\nputs \" entered myproc\""} 1' RS= proc-file.tcl
```

Gives this file:

```
proc myproc { {filename "input.txt"}
{var1 "x"} 
{var2 "y"}
{var3 "z"}
{var4 ""}
{var5 "0"}
{var6 "0"}
{var7 0}
} {
puts " entered myproc"
```

Comment: but, it want it to look for proc , the start of a line & look for the line that has } {

Comment: works now. But how to update the file? Also, how does it work, Can you post a commented version too ?

Comment: You can do: **`awk '/^ *proc/ {$0 = $0 "\nputs \" entered myproc\""} 1' RS= proc-file.tcl > _tmp && mv _tmp proc-file.tcl `**

Comment: But, it fails for a proc like this & adds the puts just outside the function..
proc myproc2 { N val } {
# comment line
    set ret {}
    for { set i 0 } { $i < $N } { incr i } { lappend ret $val }
    return $ret
}

Comment: also, for some proc, where the no of lines in the header are different, it prints them at different offsets from the "} {" match.

Comment: Post those sample inputs in question so that I can investigate and edit my answer.